# Why (char)433 is equal to -79'+-' in c++?

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11

When I type cast `433` to `char` I get [this](https://scontent-mrs1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/1614452_405894359596886_3194208636186369435_o.jpg). 
How does 433 equal to `-79` while `ASCII` for `4` & `3` are `52` & `51` respectively, according to [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) table.

Comment: It's called overflow because `char` goes 0-255.

Comment: Well, `char` can be either signed *or* unsigned, so it's range is either -128 to 127, or 0 to 255 (for eight-bit `char`).

Comment: The ASCII values for `'3'` and `'4'` have nothing to do with this. If you bring those into the picture, it would be like `(char)52 == '4'`. You're picking a number that's out of range instead of 52 there. The digits of that number have nothing to do with the character, just like 5 and 2 have nothing to do with `'4'`.

Answer (score 6):

The decimal number `433` is `0x1b1`, and is an `int` and is usually 32 bits longs. What happens when you cast it to a `char` (which usually have 8 bits) is that all but the lowest 8 bits are just thrown away, leaving you with `0xb1` which is `-79` as a signed [two-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) 8-bit integer.